# Stripe namespace giving error in php

Tags: stripe-payments

I have used php library for stripe payment, When I call the charge page it gives 500 internal server error by this namespace errors and also the require init.php giving error.

My server PHP Version 5.2.17

SO Please suggest me how to solve this problem..

i.stack.imgur.com/c05Hr.png

Answer (score 1):

The latest release of Stripe's PHP bindings (2.*) require you to have PHP 5.3.3 or later on your server as explained [here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#requirements). Since you're on PHP 5.2.17 you'd need to either:

1. Use the [legacy](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#legacy-version-support) version of the bindings (1.18.0)
2. Upgrade the version of PHP on your server to at least 5.3.3